# Detect duplicate keys in python

Tags: python

I had a college exercise which contains a question which asked to write a function which returns how many times a particular key repeats in an object in python. after researching on dictionaries I know that python automatically ignores duplicate keys only keeping the last one. I tried to loop over each key the conventional way:

```
dictt = {'a' : 22, 'a' : 33, 'c' : 34, 'd' : 456}
lookFor = 'a'
times = 0
for k,v in dictt.items():
      if k == lookFor:
          times = times + 1
```

This would return 1. even if I check the length of the dictionary it shows 3 meaning only one of the key 'a' was counted.

Comment: dicts cannot contain duplicate keys.  The first `a` is replaced by the second one.

Comment: Dictionaries are maps, so they cannot have duplicate keys, otherwise they wouldn't know what value you want from the given key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary does not contain the duplicate keys. The last entered `key` will be stored by the dictionary.

```
dictt = {'a' : 22, 'a' : 33, 'c' : 34, 'd' : 456}
# This is your dictionary.
# Now print the dictionary to see it.
print(dictt)
```

Output :-

```
{'a': 33, 'c': 34, 'd': 456} 
# Now this is your dictionary. Now on whatever the operation you will perform, you are perfroming on this dictionary.
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, dictionaries don't have duplicate keys. Read the [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/). Trying to add a new item with the same key of an already existing one, will overwrite the older item. Try printing the items in your dict:

```
dictt = {'a' : 22, 'a' : 33, 'c' : 34, 'd' : 456}
for x, y in dictt.items():
  print(x, y)
```

Output:

```
a 33
c 34
d 456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys, it will be rewriten.

However you could make a new data type for it.

```
class Dictlist(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self[key]
        except KeyError:
            super(Dictlist, self).__setitem__(key, [])
        self[key].append(value)
```

Example use

```
>>> d = dictlist.Dictlist()
>>> d['test'] = 1
>>> d['test'] = 2
>>> d['test'] = 3
>>> d
{'test': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> d['other'] = 100
>>> d
{'test': [1, 2, 3], 'other': [100]}
```

To answer your question using `Dictlist` data type

```
dictt = dictlist.Dictlist()
dictt['a'] = 22
dictt['a'] = 33
dictt['c'] = 34
dictt['d'] = 456
lookFor = 'a'
len(dictt['a'])
```